# Virtualmin Fresh Install What Is The Username And Password?

Tags: virtualmin

I have successfully installed Virtualmin GPL on my Debian 5 VPS I have then went to https://example.com:10000 and I got the login page.

What username and password should I use to log in? I don't remembered choosing a username or password during installation :)

Comment: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/webmin-installation-and-configuration-in-ubuntu-linux.html

Comment: If you down-vote a q. Please say so why...

I found nothing wrong with the questions

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try root as the user and whatever your root password is as the password.